# Multiple fetch requests with setState in React and pie chart

Tags: reactjs, axios, promise, fetch-api, pie-chart

My query was taking more than 2 mins to execute, henceforth it was getting timeout in browser. So now I have break the query and now running as a separate APIs which is helpful, but now I don't know how to handle these three requests so that it can render the data.

Note: The API's data are getting stored in the State component of react, here it is "Data".

Now I have a logic but can anyone give me a direction how to implement it.

Logic: Before storing the result of API's directly into state component, we can store it into different array, then we can iterate through this array for the use of pie chart then this data can be stored into the state component which can be used to render the pie chart in "Render" function.

Here the I am making three different API calls at the same time and storing it, here the result of the API's are directly been stored in the state component:

```
componentDidMount() {
    Promise.all([
      fetch("http://localhost:4000/api/EMEA/E_claimQuarter"),
      fetch("http://localhost:4000/api/EMEA/E_claimQuarter1"),
      fetch("http://localhost:4000/api/EMEA/E_claimQuarter2")
    ])
      .then(([res1, res2, res3]) => 

      Promise.all([res1.json(), res2.json(), res3.json()]))

      .then(([data1, data2, data3]) => 

        this.setState({
          // Data: data1, data2, data3,
          Data: {
            labels: [
              "FY19 Q1[NOV-JAN]",
              "FY19 Q2[FEB-APR]",
              "FY18 Q3[SEP-NOV]"
            ],
            datasets: [
              {
                label: "",
                data: data1,
                backgroundColor: [
                  "rgba(255,105,145,0.6)",
                  "rgba(155,100,210,0.6)",
                  "rgb(63, 191, 191)"
                ]
              }
            ]
          }
        })
      );
  }
```

This is how you handle the data form API and loop through it then render this data for the various charts which is in my case is Pie Chart:

```
ComponentDidMount() {
    axios.get(`http://localhost:4000/api/APJ/A_claimQuarter`)
***************************************************************
    .then(res => {
          const claims = res.data;
          let claim = [];

          claims.forEach(element => {
            claim.push(element.CNT1);

          });
********************************************************************
          this.setState({ 
            Data: {
              labels: ['FY19 Q1[NOV-JAN]','FY19 Q2[FEB-APR]','FY18[SEP-NOV]'],
              datasets:[
                 {
                    label:'',
                    data: claim ,

                    backgroundColor:[
                     'rgba(255,105,145,0.6)',
                     'rgba(155,100,210,0.6)',
                     'rgb(63, 191, 191)'

                  ]
                 }
              ]
           }
           });
       })
}
```

Comment: Looks like you have figured it out. What is the issue you are facing ?

Comment: See now I have highlighted the code also, that I want to implement in the "Promise.all" code, but I don't know how to do it, this is the issue here.

Comment: Because I don't know how to handle the request from three different APIs for the rendering for the pie chart

Comment: could not understand ur questio.. probably should re-phrase it..

Comment: What could you not able to understand, can you tell me properly ?

Answer (score 1):

I have made some modifications and now it is working fine for me, if anyone want the answer you can look at mine, it is 100% working:

```
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      Data: []
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    Promise.all([
      fetch("http://localhost:4000/api/EMEA/E_claimQuarter"),
      fetch("http://localhost:4000/api/EMEA/E_claimQuarter1"),
      fetch("http://localhost:4000/api/EMEA/E_claimQuarter2")
    ])
      .then(([res1, res2, res3]) => Promise.all([res1.json(), res2.json(), res3.json()]))
      .then(([data1, data2, data3]) => 
       { 
        console.log(typeof(data1));

        const array = [...data1, ...data2, ...data3];
        // const A = JSON.strigify(array);
        console.log('hi');
        console.log(array);
        console.log(data1);
        // console.log(A);
        let claim = [];

        array.forEach(element => {
        claim.push(element.COUNT);
        });
        console.log(claim);
        this.setState({
          // Data: data1, data2, data3,
          Data: {
            labels: [
              "FY19 Q1[NOV-JAN]",
              "FY19 Q2[FEB-APR]",
              "FY18 Q3[SEP-NOV]"
            ],
            datasets: [
              {
                label: "",
                data: claim,
                backgroundColor: [
                  "rgba(255,105,145,0.6)",
                  "rgba(155,100,210,0.6)",
                  "rgb(63, 191, 191)"
                ]
              }
            ]
          }
        })
       });
  }
```

Comment: I feel you should be looking for a solution which is data driven, ie not hard coded for three Quarters. Say one day you wanted a graph of four quarters, would it not be better to have a generalised function that could handle any number of quarters? It would not be too difficult to write.

Comment: thanks for the heads up @Roamer, now the project is in just prototype mode, once it is fully worked on the production mode then I will optimize the project further more.

Comment: I have overwritten my answer with something based on your own answer.

Comment: Because I am new to this whole web development

Comment: Understand - you are doing well.

Answer (score 0):

Based on OP's own answer, here's a more generalised solution :

```
componentDidMount(graphData) {
    return Promise.all(graphData.map(dataObj => dataObj.url))
    .then(results => Promise.all(results.map(res => res.json())))
    .then(results => this.setState({
        'Data': {
            'labels': graphData.map(dataObj => dataObj.label),
            'datasets': [
                {
                    'label': '',
                    'data': results.reduce((prev, next) => prev.concat(next), []),
                    'backgroundColor': graphData.map(dataObj => dataObj.bgColor)
                }
            ]
        }
    }));
}
```

As you see, Array methods `.map()` and `.reduce()` make for some nice compact code.

Call as follows:

```
var quartersData = [
    { 'url':'http://localhost:4000/api/EMEA/E_claimQuarter', 'label':'FY19 Q1[NOV-JAN]', 'bgColor':'rgba(255,105,145,0.6)' },
    { 'url':'http://localhost:4000/api/EMEA/E_claimQuarter1', 'label':'FY19 Q2[FEB-APR]', 'bgColor':'rgba(155,100,210,0.6)' },
    { 'url':'http://localhost:4000/api/EMEA/E_claimQuarter2', 'label':'FY18 Q3[SEP-NOV]', 'bgColor':'rgb(63, 191, 191)' }
];

componentDidMount(quartersData)
.then(() => {
    console.log('complete');
});
```